# Java - Linked List Generics Sublists

Tags: java, list, linked-list

So I dont have much experience working with Linked List in java and I got this assignment that requires to store values on a Linked List. In summary is creating class that deals with Lisp expressions. In particular, it creates a reference based linked list from an expression, and implements a number of methods to perform operations on the list. As provided by my professor, he use the tokenizer to break the expression. Example:

```
        parse("(+ 3 5 ( 23.2 -1a 1/2 \"abc\" ) ) ");
```

And my assignment is to add it to a simple linked list, but my problem is that for every open parentheses there's a new list and a parentheses inside this is a sublist.

For the case: (4 * (45 + 3) - (7/5))

(45 + 3) is a sublist or list.

(7/5) is a sublist or list

4 is integer

* symbol

45 integer

+ symbol

3 integer

- symbol

7/5 ratio

My professor told me this: "So, the sublist or list you have to do the same as the complete list, that means that the recognizer process can be recursive."

I have a Lisp generic class, a LinkedList class, and a class for breaking the expression into tokens.

Any idea?

Comment: Sounds more like a *tree* than a list.

Comment: @BrianRoach yeah, I thought the same too, but Im required to build a Linked List instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want here is a [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) implementation. When you have two types that you want to treat similarly, you make a composite. Parsers typically have node and leaf classes, or compound and terminal expressions. If you have both implement the same interface, then you can easily make a list that describes the parsing process because each node in the list could be a collection of other nodes. So your instincts are right, that you are dealing with a tree. A tree that looks like a list is usually a Composite.